# Failled to start monitoring emulator 5554 Problem

Tags: android, emulation, monitoring

i'm totally new to Android programing and to programing at all. i'm having trouble making my first easiest app "Hello world". i'm stuck with that "Monitoring Emulator 5554" problem, and i can not resolve it. i've tried to restart ADB but it doesn't work.

here are images of my screen.

before i clicked Screenshot

[image]

after i clicked Screenshot

[image]